# How to use mikroC oscillator frequency in my code?

Tags: pic, frequency, oscillator

I am using mikroC pro for PIC. In the "Edit Project" window there is an option for setting oscillator frequency. I want to use that value in my code. I think it can be used like something that is defined using #define, but I don't know the name of it. Does anyone know it?

Comment: I believe the "Edit Project" thing is writing the configuration registers not accessible from the code.

Comment: There is no oscillator frequency in config registers. BTW some of mikroC functions use it (delay, uartint, spiinit, etc).

Comment: Then look at their implementations. Aren't the sources provided?

Comment: No, there is no source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MiKroC has inline functions `Clock_MHz()` and `Clock_kHz()`, which return the device clock frequency rounded to the nearest MHz or kHz respectively.

They are documented in the help system under "MickroC PRO for PIC specifics/Built-in Routines".